# Merging two datatool databases from different files but with the same columns

Tags: datatool

Consider the following example code. This is not quite an MWE, because it contains elements that are strictly unnecessary.

I'd like to merge the two datatool databases, `corrDB` and `docDB` vertically (by row) and then sort them by the key column `RowID`. That last part, I think I know how to do, approximately. Though I am not sure if `\dtlletterindexcompare` is the right comparison method to use to sort keys of the form xxxx.xx.xx.yy where x are integers and the y are numbers. I don't know if I should ask a separate question about this, but in any case, feel free to comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}

\newcommand{\PrintDocTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1in} c c p{3.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
    & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [%
    \ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\newcommand{\PrintCorrTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to searchc
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} l l p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
    & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [%
    \ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & \From & \To & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{corr.csv}
  2011.09.09.ab,   Sep 09 2011, AB,  CD , more stuff
  2011.09.26.xy,   Sep 26 2011, XY,  WZ , some more stuff
  2011.09.26.ab,   Sep 26 2011, AB,  CD , yet more stuff
  2011.09.09,      Sep 09 2011, CD,  AB , stuff
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{doc.csv}
  2011.09.26.cd,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 1
  2011.09.26.ce,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 2
  2011.09.26.zz,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Subject}]{docDB}{doc.csv}
\newtermaddfield[docDB]{From}{From}{}
\newtermaddfield[docDB]{To}{To}{}
\PrintDocTable{docDB}{Documents}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,From,To,Subject}]{corrDB}{corr.csv}
\dtlsort{RowID}{corrDB}{\dtlletterindexcompare}
\PrintCorrTable{corrDB}{Correspondence}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merging of tables with [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) is not natively supported. You'll either have to process the tables externally, or create a new table that represents the union of the tables to be merged. This latter approach is used below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datagidx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}

\newcommand{\PrintDocTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 = caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1in} c c p{3.5in}}
    \caption{#3} \\
    & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [%
    \ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\newcommand{\PrintCorrTable}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to searchc
 % #3 = caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} l l p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3} \\
    & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [%
    \ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}
    ]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & \From & \To & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{corr.csv}
  2011.09.09.ab,   Sep 09 2011, AB,  CD , more stuff
  2011.09.26.xy,   Sep 26 2011, XY,  WZ , some more stuff
  2011.09.26.ab,   Sep 26 2011, AB,  CD , yet more stuff
  2011.09.09,      Sep 09 2011, CD,  AB , stuff
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{doc.csv}
  2011.09.26.cd,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 1
  2011.09.26.ce,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 2
  2011.09.26.zz,   Sep 26 2011,  Doc 3
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Subject}]{docDB}{doc.csv}
\newtermaddfield[docDB]{From}{From}{}
\newtermaddfield[docDB]{To}{To}{}
\PrintDocTable{docDB}{Documents}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,From,To,Subject}]{corrDB}{corr.csv}
\dtlsort{RowID}{corrDB}{\dtlletterindexcompare}
\PrintCorrTable{corrDB}{Correspondence}

\makeatletter
% Merge two tables
\DTLnewdb{docDBcorrDB}% Create new merged table
% Read all entries from docDB and insert into docDBcorrDB
\DTLforeach*{docDB}{\docDBRowID=RowID,\docDBDate=Date,\docDBSubject=Subject}{
  \DTLnewrow{docDBcorrDB}
  {\let\DTLnewdbentry\relax% Avoid expansion of \DTLnewdbentry when using \protected@xdef below
   \protected@xdef\insertnewdbentry{%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\docDBRowID}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Date}{\docDBDate}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Subject}{\docDBSubject}%
  }}\insertnewdbentry
}
% Read all entries from corrDB and insert into docDBcorrDB
\DTLforeach*{corrDB}{\corrDBRowID=RowID,\corrDBDate=Date,\corrDBFrom=From,\corrDBTo=To,\corrDBSubject=Subject}{
  \DTLnewrow{docDBcorrDB}
  {\let\DTLnewdbentry\relax% Avoid expansion of \DTLnewdbentry when using \protected@xdef below
   \protected@xdef\insertnewdbentry{%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\corrDBRowID}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Date}{\corrDBDate}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{From}{\corrDBFrom}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{To}{\corrDBTo}%
     \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Subject}{\corrDBSubject}%
  }}\insertnewdbentry
}
\makeatother

% Sort database
\dtlsort{RowID}{docDBcorrDB}{\dtlletterindexcompare}
% Print new merged table
\begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} l l p{2.5in}}
  \caption{Merge table (Documents + Correspondence)} \\
  & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject} \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \DTLforeach
  {docDBcorrDB}{%
    \RowID=RowID,%
    \Date=Date,%
    \From=From,%
    \To=To,%
    \Subject=Subject%
  }{%
    \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
  }%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Of course, the construction of the `docDBcorrDB` database uses some knowledge of `docDB` and `corrDB`, since `docDB` doesn't have the `From` and/or `To` field. However, that's typical for query constructions and require some accommodation anyway. Either way, you'll have to process each table separately to get the information, whether they have the same structure or not.

The main principle behind the merge is to read entries one-by-one from the first database and constructing a "new entry" (in the form of `\insertnewdbentry`). Let's look at how this is performed. Here's the main construction for the first table (with line numbers):

```
1: \DTLforeach*{docDB}{\docDBRowID=RowID,\docDBDate=Date,\docDBSubject=Subject}{
2:   \DTLnewrow{docDBcorrDB}
3:   {\let\DTLnewdbentry\relax% Avoid expansion of \DTLnewdbentry when using \protected@xdef below
4:    \protected@xdef\insertnewdbentry{%
5:      \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\docDBRowID}%
6:      \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Date}{\docDBDate}%
7:      \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Subject}{\docDBSubject}%
8:   }}\insertnewdbentry
9: }
```

We cycle through each entry (line 1) using `\DTLforeach`. The starred version is used as the database will only be read, not written to. Each of the fields are assigned to specific macros (field `RowID` will be assigned to `\docDBRowID`, ...). For each record that is read, we create a new record in the merged database (line 2). The next block (lines 3-8) is meant to add a single record (in this case containing 3 different fields) to the new merged table. It creates `\insertnewdbentry` inside a group. However, since it's created using an `\...xdef`, the actual definition will be global. The reason for using an e`x`panded `def`inition is because the values for each field has to be expanded before placing them into the database. That is, if you just used

```
\DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\docDBRowID}
```

the first record's field `RowID` would have the value `\docDBRowID` and not `2011.09.26.cd`, as the macro `\docDBRowID` is not expanded before being stored; `\...xdef` ensures expansion. Using `\protected@xdef` makes sure that certain macros that require (or already use) `\protect`ion is not expanded. However, this does require the construction to be surrounded by a [`\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764). Now the tricky part is to expand `\docDBRowID` but not expand `\DTLnewdbentry`... The easy way around this is to set it to `\relax` (line 3). That way a `\protected@xdef` will not expand it (since `\relax` is not expandable) but it will expand `\docDBRowID`. When the group is closed (line 8), the value of `\DTLnewdbentry` is restored to what it is supposed to originally. As such, `\insertnewdbentry` will contain expanded versions of `\docDBRowID`, `\docDBDate` and `\docDBSubject` while keeping `\DTLnewdbentry` intact. Finally, after `\insertnewdbentry` is constructed, it's executed (still line 8) to now insert the correct values into the new database.

This process is repeated for each record in the first database, as well as the second database.

With the final database `docDBcorrDB` constructed, it's handled like any other database.

---

The [`datatool` user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) mentions something about this expansion issue on p 38, but also provides a work-around (not included above). Setting the boolean switch `\dtlexpandnewvalue` will ensure that values are expanded *before* they are inserted into the database. Using this approach, the construction may seem simpler if you use

```
\dtlexpandnewvalue% Values to be inserted into database should be expanded first
% Merge two tables
\DTLnewdb{docDBcorrDB}% Create new merged table
% Read all entries from docDB and insert into docDBcorrDB
\DTLforeach*{docDB}{\docDBRowID=RowID,\docDBDate=Date,\docDBSubject=Subject}{
  \DTLnewrow{docDBcorrDB}
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\docDBRowID}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Date}{\docDBDate}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Subject}{\docDBSubject}%
}
% Read all entries from corrDB and insert into docDBcorrDB
\DTLforeach*{corrDB}{\corrDBRowID=RowID,\corrDBDate=Date,\corrDBFrom=From,\corrDBTo=To,\corrDBSubject=Subject}{
  \DTLnewrow{docDBcorrDB}
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{RowID}{\corrDBRowID}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Date}{\corrDBDate}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{From}{\corrDBFrom}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{To}{\corrDBTo}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{docDBcorrDB}{Subject}{\corrDBSubject}%
}
```

Comment: Hi Werner. Thanks, for the very nice answer. I suspected that datatool did not support this directly. Can you elaborate a bit on the TeX programming you are doing, for the benefit of non-experts? Also, I've added NULL values for `From` and `To` in docDB, so it doesn't require special handling...